# UIButton doesn't appear on UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, interface-builder

I have a UIToolbar where I have dragged a UIButton. When I set the button properties to Custom, and assign an image (or background image) the graphics don't appear. However, when I give it a custom text, the text will appear. Why is it that the images don't appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the image is present in your bundle/project?

Are you setting the button's image for `UIControlStateNormal`?

Comment: Yes to both. Interesting, when I use a separate image, it appears fine. I'm wondering if something is wrong with the image that I'm using?

Comment: Can you display that image in a `UIImageView`? Have you tried a clean build to ensure all the resources are being correctly bundled?

Comment: Yes, that image does load in UIImageView and even in a normal photo editor. Build cleaned.

Comment: Is the button's alpha set to 0? Is it set to be opaque? Is it the same with all images or just one image?

Comment: Initialize the `UIImage` object separately (before the call to `setImage:forState:`) and make sure it's not `nil` for some reason.